# How to handle execvp(...) errors after fork()?

Tags: c++, linux, posix, exec, fork

I do the regular thing:

- fork()
- execvp(cmd, ) in child

If execvp fails because no cmd is found, how can I notice this error in parent process?

Comment: No, because the forked child is a separate process with its own address space and its own independent copy of errno. The parent can't see the child's errno.

Comment: Removed that stupid comment. Thanks Andrew Medico and roe.

Comment: Isn't this a job for some simple IPC?  Doing so affords you more than 8-bits of an exit status.  And you also get to be sure that your execv failed, as opposed to the spawned process failing.  I guess it depends on how much you care about your child not actually firing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The well-known [self-pipe trick](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) can be [adapted](http://lkml.org/lkml/2006/7/10/300) for this purpose.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int pipefds[2];
    int count, err;
    pid_t child;

    if (pipe(pipefds)) {
        perror("pipe");
        return EX_OSERR;
    }
    if (fcntl(pipefds[1], F_SETFD, fcntl(pipefds[1], F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC)) {
        perror("fcntl");
        return EX_OSERR;
    }

    switch (child = fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        return EX_OSERR;
    case 0:
        close(pipefds[0]);
        execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
        write(pipefds[1], &errno, sizeof(int));
        _exit(0);
    default:
        close(pipefds[1]);
        while ((count = read(pipefds[0], &err, sizeof(errno))) == -1)
            if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EINTR) break;
        if (count) {
            fprintf(stderr, "child's execvp: %s\n", strerror(err));
            return EX_UNAVAILABLE;
        }
        close(pipefds[0]);
        puts("waiting for child...");
        while (waitpid(child, &err, 0) == -1)
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                perror("waitpid");
                return EX_SOFTWARE;
            }
        if (WIFEXITED(err))
            printf("child exited with %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(err));
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(err))
            printf("child killed by %d\n", WTERMSIG(err));
    }
    return err;
}
```

Here's a complete program.

```
$ ./a.out foo
child's execvp: No such file or directory
$ (sleep 1 && killall -QUIT sleep &); ./a.out sleep 60
waiting for child...
child killed by 3
$ ./a.out true
waiting for child...
child exited with 0
```

How this works:

Create a pipe, and make the write endpoint `CLOEXEC`: it auto-closes when an `exec` is successfully performed.

In the child, try to `exec`.  If it succeeds, we no longer have control, but the pipe is closed.  If it fails, write the failure code to the pipe and exit.

In the parent, try to read from the other pipe endpoint.  If `read` returns zero, then the pipe was closed and the child must have `exec` successfully.  If `read` returns data, it's the failure code that our child wrote.

Comment: This solution, quite simply, rocks.

Comment: There should be an extra set of parenthesis inside the switch statement, to ensure the compiler that it's meant as a assignment statement

Comment: @TaylorFlores: ?? The compiler understands the syntax just fine.  Many compilers *warn* on a bare assignment inside an `if`, as equality checks are more common there, but there's no reason to do that in a `switch`.

Comment: In the child you use `sizeof(int)` to write the `errno` while in the parent you're using `sizeof(errno)` to read the `errno`. Whichi one is better to be used?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai POSIX says the type of `errno` is `int`, so it's the same either way. I didn't realize I was being inconsistent though, oops.

Comment: what is the point of looping continuously on the `read`? What could potentially wrong go wrong here? And why is then `break` the correct response? Shouldn't I instead exit with an error message?

Answer (score 6):

You terminate the child (by calling [_exit()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit)) and then the parent can notice this (through e.g. [waitpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)). For instance, your child could exit with an exit status of -1 to indicate failure to exec. One caveat with this is that it is impossible to tell from your parent whether the child in its original state (i.e. before exec) returned -1 or if it was the newly executed process.

As suggested in the comments below, using an "unusual" return code would be appropriate to make it easier to distinguish between your specific error and one from the exec()'ed program. Common ones are 1, 2, 3 etc. while higher numbers 99, 100, etc. are more unusual. You should keep your numbers below 255 (unsigned) or 127 (signed) to increase portability.

Since waitpid blocks your application (or rather, the thread calling it) you will either need to put it on a background thread or use the signalling mechanism in POSIX to get information about child process termination. See the SIGCHLD signal and the [sigaction](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) function to hook up a listener.

You could also do some error checking before forking, such as making sure the executable exists.

If you use something like [Glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/), there are utility functions to do this, and they come with pretty good error reporting. Take a look at the "[spawning processes](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.22/glib-Spawning-Processes.html)" section of the manual.

Comment: isn't the exit status 8 bit unsigned? (-1 -> 255)

Comment: It's just 8 bits of data. It doesn't matter whether you interpret them as signed of unsigned. (just be consistent) I'm not sure what the POSIX standard says, but it's quite common to return negative values from main() to indicate error

Comment: Won't waitpid() block my parent process?

Comment: Yes it will, there's also a SIGCHLD signal that you can trap in your application. That will make the OS call your function whenever one of your child applications terminate. You can from there examine the return value. Use the signal or sigaction calls to listen to that signal (it's ignored by default)

Comment: Naturally, signed 8bit will turn 255 into -1, but I guess most people would use an int, which commonly carries 32 bits turning your -1 unsigned into 255 signed.. Just a thought, maybe it doesn't happen.

Comment: also you can speficy a timeout (which can be zero), which can be used for polling, if you don't want to rely on sigchld.

Comment: Suggestion: use an unusual exit status - 99 or something along those lines - to indicate failure to exec. While the executed process might exit with that same exit status, it is pretty improbable. Using 0, 1, -1, 2 is a bit risky; those statuses are used rather regularly. Note that the shell maps the exit status of a process that dies as a result of a signal to '128+signal-number'. Try 'sleep 30' and interrupt it and then 'echo $?'; I get exit status 130 (which is expected because SIGINT = 2). So, avoid exit statuses 128..160 or thereabouts.

Comment: Good suggestion about unusal status Jonathan. Will update my post to include this.

Regarding SIGINT, you can (and SHOULD!) avoid that by using the WIFEXITED() macro. This evaluates to TRUE if the process died a normal death and FALSE otherwise (e.g. killed by a signal)

Comment: Don't use exit() after fork() - it can hang the process on some platforms - use _exit().

Answer (score 1):

Not should you wonder how you **can** notice it in parent process, but also you should keep in mind that you **must** notice the error in parent process.  That's especially true for multithreaded applications.

After execvp you **must** place a call to function that terminates the process in any case.  You should not call any complex functions that interact with C library (such as stdio), since effects of them may mingle with pthreads of libc functionality of parent process.  So you can't print a message with `printf()` in child process and have to inform parent about the error instead.

The easiest way, among the other, is passing return code.  Supply nonzero argument to `_exit()` function (see note below) you used to terminate the child and then examine the return code in the parent.  Here's the example:

```
int pid, stat;
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0){
   // Child process
   execvp(cmd);
   if (errno == ENOENT)
     _exit(-1);
   _exit(-2);
}

wait(&stat);
if (!WIFEXITED(stat)) { // Error happened 
...
}
```

---

Instead of `_exit()`, you might think of `exit()` function, but it's incorrect, since this function will do a part of the C-library cleanup that should be done only when *parent* process terminates.  Instead, use `_exit()` function, that doesn't do such a cleanup.

Comment: Don't use exit() after fork, use _exit().

Comment: @Douglas Leeder , thank you for pointing out this huge flaw.  I fixed the post.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use `_exit()` not `exit()` - see http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/vfork.html - NB: applies to `fork()` as well as `vfork()`.

2) The problem with doing more complicated IPC than the exit status, is that you have a shared memory map, and it's possible to get some nasty state if you do anything too complicated - e.g. in multithreaded code, one of the killed threads (in the child) could have been holding a lock.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the `wait`/`waitpid` functions in the parent process. You can specify a `status` variable that holds info about the status of the process that terminated. The downside is that the parent process is blocked until the child process finishes execution.

Comment: have a look at sigchld if you don't want to block the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime exec fails in a subprocess, you should use kill(getpid(),SIGKILL) and the parent should always have a signal handler for SIGCLD and tell the user of the program, in the appropriate way, that the process was not successfully started.