# How to programmatically run a command with low IO priority and high niceness value on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd, nice

Is there a way to basically call `system()`, but with a predefined niceness value (20) and low IO priority from Objective-C?

(The low IO priority setting I'm talking about is the one [`launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) has)

I'm trying to launch `/usr/bin/purge` from within my Objective-C program.

It would also be ideal for the method to be approved for the Mac App Store.

Comment: Generally, if you need to launch a daemon, you use [XPC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)

Comment: @CodaFi: what I really want is to just run `/usr/bin/purge` with low priority, XPC is still the right thing to use in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: Fork and exec no more, since OSX can't really `fork` right. Single thread magic:

```
setiopolicy_np(IOPOL_TYPE_DISK, IOPOL_SCOPE_PROCESS, IOPOL_THROTTLE);
system("nice -n 20 /usr/bin/purge");
setiopolicy_np(IOPOL_TYPE_DISK, IOPOL_SCOPE_PROCESS, IOPOL_DEFAULT);
```

This can go anywhere, in a dispatch block if you want, or anywhere in your application. No `fork` in sight. Also, feel free to replace `system` with `NSTask` if you want to stay ObjCish.

---

How about a good old `fork`n`exec`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
```

And:

```
if(fork()) {
  /* Set IO priority */
  setiopolicy_np(IOPOL_TYPE_DISK, IOPOL_SCOPE_PROCESS, IOPOL_THROTTLE);
  /*IO priority is inherited*/
  execl("nice", "-n", "20", "/usr/bin/purge");
}
```

Let's walk through this:

- `fork`: Nothing to see here
- `setiopolicy_np`: This is the place where we set IO priority (like launchd). Here are the arguments:

  - `IOPOL_TYPE_DISK`: We want to limit Disk I/O. There is no other option available anyway.
  - `IOPOL_SCOPE_PROCESS`: Affects this whole process
  - `IOPOL_THROTTLE`: This is the policy itself. Accouring to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/setiopolicy_np.3.html), it specifies this:

  > I/Os with THROTTLE policy are called THROTTLE I/Os.  If a THROTTLE I/O
  >   request occurs
  >                         within a small time window (usually a fraction of a second) of  another NORMAL I/O
  >                         request, the thread that issues the THROTTLE I/O is forced to sleep for a certain
  >                         interval. This slows down the thread that issues the THROTTLE I/O so that NORMAL I/Os
  >                         can utilize most of the disk I/O bandwidth.  Furthermore, a NORMAL I/O request may
  >                         bypass a previously issued THROTTLE I/O request in kernel or driver queues and be sent
  >                         to the device first.  In some circumstances, very large THROTTLE I/O requests will be
  >                         broken into smaller requests which are then issued serially.

I/O priority is inherited, and the `nice` part of the command sets the nice value.

Comment: Sounds good, but do you know if this is allowed on the Mac App Store?

Comment: @houbysoft: Let me do some checking.

Comment: @houbysoft: It should. App Sandbox allows read-only access to `/usr/bin` (and all other command directories), and I can't find anything to indicate that it limits any systems calls beyond the ones that access the file system. Now, whether `purge` can run in the sandbox is a different issue, but that's not the question.

Comment: Just tried it and got a lot of messages about `fork` not being safe -- same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707572/fork-within-cocoa-application for example. I replaced the fork call with a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ...` call, which seems to work. The policy should still be inherited correctly, right?

Comment: @houbysoft: Don't think so, it isn't a new process. You're setting the policy for your parent process too. Try my edit (anyway, if it complains, it doesn't matter, we're not using any Obj-C anything after the fork). (<rant>I hate these little UNIX things that OSX just can't do right. Linux can do *anything* after a fork if you manage your memory right </rant>)

Comment: I tried using exec as well, but it still printed all the warnings. I think it's `nice` itself that's causing it since I'm guessing it forks to launch `purge`. I guess it would still work despite the warnings, but I doubt it would make it through the App Store approval process. Honestly for my application it's not a big deal to have low IO priority since it never really uses IO anyway so I think I'll keep my `dispatch` call. As long as the `purge` process gets the low IO policy, I don't really care.

Comment: @houbysoft: Ok. Hope I helped a little ;).

Comment: @houbysoft: wait! I have an idea!

Comment: Yeah I actually added that to my code before, it seems like it works. I submitted to the Mac App Store to test if they will have any issue with this. I'll give you the bounty once they accept (if they don't respond in time I'll just award it anyway).

Comment: Seems like they're taking their time haha. Giving bounty now then, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to accomplish this would be using the [taskpolicy(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/taskpolicy.8.html) tool with the *-b* option:

```
system("/usr/sbin/taskpolicy -b /usr/bin/purge");
```

With the *-b* option taskpolicy uses [setpriority(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man2/setpriority.2.html) to set the background priority(PRIO_DARWIN_BG)

Setting a process to PRIO_DARWIN_BG has this effect on itself and all its children:

> > "When a thread
> >          or process is in a background state the scheduling priority is set to the lowest value, disk IO is
> >          throttled (with behavior similar to using setiopolicy_np(3) to set a throttleable policy), and network
> >          IO is throttled for any sockets opened after going into background state.  Any previously opened sockets ets are not affected."