# Determine whether or not execvp succeeded or failed

Tags: c, unix

I'm looking for a way to determine whether or not the function execvp succeeded or failed. I do know that if it returns then it has failed, but I'm looking for a case in which the command launched from execvp has failed. Such as in the case where "ls" is trying to list a non-existent folder. From this I plan to add support for logic operators (e.g. &&, ||). Thanks.

```
else {
    int status;
    if (wait(&status) < 0) {
        perror("wait failed");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (status == 0) {
        success = true;
    }
    else {
        success = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first `fork()` a new process, then have that new process call `execvp`.  The parent process should then call `wait()`, which will allow it to retrieve the exit status of the command you ran (`ls`, in this case).

When checking the return status retrieved from `wait()`, be sure to use `WIFEXITED()` to ensure the child exited normally, and use `WEXITSTATUS()` to extract the exit status.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(1);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    execlp("/bin/ls","ls","-l","xyz",NULL);
    perror("exec failed");
    exit(1);
} else {
    int status;
    pid = wait(&status);
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("pid %d exited with status %d\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    } else {
        printf("pid %d exited abnormally\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now I have this, at the end of my checks to see if fork failed. But I don't think I'm looking for the right information from status.

`else if (c_pid > 0) {
pid = waitpid(c_pid, &status, 0); 
if (pid == -1) {perror("wait failed");
     exit(0);
 }
        if (status == 0) {
    success = true;
 }
        success = false;

        /*
        if ((pid = wait(&status)) < 0) {
            perror("wait...");
            exit(1);
        }*/
    }`

Comment: @xythyl Update your question with your code.  It's impossible to read within a comment.

Comment: Thank you! Also, how to I properly post code on here? For some reason it didn't hold any of the formatting.

Comment: @xythyl Paste the code into your question, then press the "`{}`" button at the top of the edit window to format it.

Comment: How does `wait` retrieve a positive status? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710003/execvp-fork-how-to-catch-unsuccessful-executions#comment18829737_13710132) it doesn't seem like wait is actually able to determine a successful execvp or not.