# Can posix read() receive less than requested 4 bytes from a pipe?

Tags: linux, pipe, posix

A program from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586277/6362199 uses the system call read() to receive exactly 4 bytes from a pipe. It assumes that the function read() returns -1, 0 or 4. Can the read() function return 1, 2 or 3 for example if it was interrupted by a signal?

In the man page read(2) there is:

> On  success,  the  number  of bytes read is returned (zero indicates
>   end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  **It
>   is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
>   requested;** this may happen for example because fewer bytes are
>   actually available right now (maybe because we were close to
>   end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a 
>   terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

Does this mean that the read() function can be interrupted during receiving such a small amount of data as 4 bytes? Should the source code from this answer be corrected?

In the man page pipe(7) there is:

> POSIX.1-2001  says  that write(2)s of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be atomic: the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous sequence.

but there is nothing similar about read().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the write is atomic, that means that the entire content is already present in the buffer when the read happens so the only way to have an incomplete read is if the kernel thread decides to yield before it's finished - which wouldn't happen here.

In general you can rely on small write()s on pipes on the same system mapping to identical read()s. 4 bytes is unquestionably far smaller than any buffer would ever be, so it will definitely be atomic.

Comment: Is there a reference where I can read that such guarantee occurs for read() similarly to write()? What is the maximum size of an atomic read?

Comment: Not that I know of. The POSIX standard http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ says regarding read():

"The standard developers considered adding atomicity requirements to a pipe or FIFO, but recognized that due to the nature of pipes and FIFOs there could be no guarantee of atomicity of reads of {PIPE_BUF} or any other size that would be an aid to applications portability."

Comment: I should clarify that this all ONLY applies to sockets which are non-blocking (O_NONBLOCK) from the reader's perspective. If it's blocking then the only way to get a nonnegative value smaller than the read length is if both the other side has cleanly closed the pipe and there was not enough data remaining before EOF (after all successful writes) to fill the requested size.

Comment: But what will be returned if the read length is big and the read() was interrupted by a signal?

Comment: @pjkozlowski, normal case: `-1` if nothing was read, or number of bytes read. But that is the normal case, which involves waiting. Waiting inside the kernel is what gets "interrupted" by signals. For as a long as `read()` doesn't need to do any waiting, and can perform operation fully on/from the buffered data, it can not be "interrupted" by a signal.